# Fabric Beta release notes and Gradle Kotlin DSL

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, google-fabric, gradle-kotlin-dsl

As stated here: https://docs.fabric.io/android/beta/gradle.html

I used to have this 2 lines in an Android app's build.gradle to upload builds to Fabric Beta with given release notes to given group aliases:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ext.betaDistributionReleaseNotesFilePath = 'app/release_notes.txt'
        ext.betaDistributionGroupAliasesFilePath = 'app/group_aliases.txt'
    }
}
```

After migrating the build.gradle files to Kotlin Gradle DSL these 2 lines have become:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ext.set("betaDistributionReleaseNotesFilePath", "app/release_notes.txt")
        ext.set("betaDistributionGroupAliasesFilePath", "app/group_aliases.txt")
    }
}
```

But they no longer work: all builds published to Fabric Beta are with blank release notes and no group aliases.

I've tried several alternative syntaxes to set the extra properties:

```
val betaDistributionReleaseNotesFilePath by extra { "app/release_notes.txt" }
```

or

```
ext["betaDistributionReleaseNotesFilePath"] = "app/release_notes.txt")
```

or

```
extra.set("betaDistributionReleaseNotesFilePath", "app/release_notes.txt")
```

or

```
project.ext.set("betaDistributionReleaseNotesFilePath", "app/release_notes.txt")
```

But results don't change.

Adding and running a debug task defined as:

```
tasks.create("myTask") {
    dependsOn("assembleDebug", "crashlyticsUploadDistributionDebug")

    doLast {

        val a = ext["betaDistributionReleaseNotesFilePath"]
        val b = ext["betaDistributionGroupAliasesFilePath"]

        println("ReleaseNotes: $a")
        println("GroupAliases: $b")
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
ReleaseNotes: app/release_notes.txt
GroupAliases: app/group_aliases.txt
```

only if the extra properties have been set using `project.ext.set()`, but still the uploaded builds have blank release notes and no group aliases.

What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 4):

you can use:

```
 configure<CrashlyticsExtension> {

            betaDistributionReleaseNotes = "xxx"
        }
```